# Whats [ASP.net]MVC doing BEFORE my controller?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, performance, mvc-mini-profiler

I've got a bit of a strange performance issue occurring with my MVC Controller, or rather before it?

According to the Mini Profiler output, there is a 120ms overhead before reaching my controller.

Does anyone know why this would be? This is on a server (Not local), that has `Compilation debug=false` set, so it's not an issue of not running in `release` mode.

Everything after it, I can tune/amend, but before it? and I'm lost..

Thoughts??

[image]

**Update**

After some performance tooling I came across [enter link description here](http://samsaffron.com/archive/2011/10/13/optimising-asp-net-mvc3-routing) & [enter link description here](http://samsaffron.com/archive/2009/11/11/Diagnosing+runaway+CPU+in+a+Net+production+application) which resulted in the below:

> Most expensive stacks
>   ------------------------------------ System.Web.HttpApplication+CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep
>   System.Web.HttpApplication+PipelineStepManager.ResumeSteps
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.BeginProcessRequestNotification
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate
>   System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationHelper
>   System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotification
>   System.Web.Hosting.UnsafeIISMethods.MgdIndicateCompletion
>   System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationHelper
>   System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotification
>   ===> Cost (1716011)
>
> Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.BuildPlanStrategy.PreBuildUp
>   Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.StrategyChain.ExecuteBuildUp
>   Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.BuilderContext.NewBuildUp
>   Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.BuildPlanStrategy.PreBuildUp
>   Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.StrategyChain.ExecuteBuildUp
>   Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.BuilderContext.NewBuildUp
>   Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.BuildPlanStrategy.PreBuildUp
>   Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.StrategyChain.ExecuteBuildUp
>   Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.BuilderContext.NewBuildUp
>   Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.BuildPlanStrategy.PreBuildUp
>   Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.StrategyChain.ExecuteBuildUp
>   Microsoft.Practices.Unity.UnityContainer.DoBuildUp
>   Microsoft.Practices.Unity.UnityContainer.DoBuildUp
>   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory+DefaultControllerActivator.Create
>   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.CreateController
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.ProcessRequestInit
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler+<>c__DisplayClass6.b__2
>   System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil+<>c__DisplayClassb`1.b__a
>   System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.ProcessInApplicationTrust
>   System.Web.HttpApplication+CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep
>   System.Web.HttpApplication+PipelineStepManager.ResumeSteps
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.BeginProcessRequestNotification
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate
>   System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationHelper
>   System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotification
>   System.Web.Hosting.UnsafeIISMethods.MgdIndicateCompletion
>   System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationHelper
>   System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotification
>   ===> Cost (936006)
>
> Microsoft.Win32.Win32Native.CoCreateGuid
>   StackExchange.Profiling.Timing..ctor
>   StackExchange.Profiling.MVCHelpers.ProfilingViewEngine.Find
>   System.Web.Mvc.ViewEngineCollection+<>c__DisplayClassc.b__a
>   System.Web.Mvc.ViewEngineCollection.Find
>   System.Web.Mvc.ViewEngineCollection.Find
>   System.Web.Mvc.ViewResult.FindView
>   System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker+<>c__DisplayClass1c.b__19
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilter
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilter
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.ExecuteCore
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.Execute
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler+<>c__DisplayClass6+<>c__DisplayClassb.b__5
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper+<>c__DisplayClass1.b__0
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler+<>c__DisplayClasse.b__d
>   System.Web.HttpApplication+CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep
>   System.Web.HttpApplication+PipelineStepManager.ResumeSteps
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.BeginProcessRequestNotification
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate
>   System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationHelper
>   System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotification
>   System.Web.Hosting.UnsafeIISMethods.MgdIndicateCompletion
>   System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationHelper
>   System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotification
>   ===> Cost (780005)

Could unity be cause some issues?

Comment: Does this delay happen with other controllers too or only this one has the delay ?

Comment: It only happens on this particular controller, my other controller that calls the same BL this does (and other surrounding logic) is much faster!

Comment: I see ... I expected a consistent behavior and was going to point at the server itself, but now I'm at a loss

Comment: It's only consistency is that it's always THAT controller method..

Answer (score 1):

You should have a look on the `The ASP.NET MVC Pipeline`

The ASP.NET MVC Pipeline can be divided into the following parts -

- `App initialisation` - n this method, you can add Route objects to the static   RouteTable.Routes collection (which is of type RouteCollection).
- `Routing Part` – Routing module tries to match the incoming URL with
  the routing table, and calling the corresponding IRouteHandler.
- `Controller creation` – the IControllerFactory creates an instance of
  the controller based on route parameters and default naming
  conventions.
- `Action Execution` – the IActionInvoker identifies the method to be
  executed, the IModelBinder validates and binds the method parameters
  and the IFilterProvider discovers filters to be applied. The Action
  returns a type ActionResult.
- `View` – the IViewEngine instantiates the correct view engine and the
  model is passed to the view. Using Model Validation Provider, the
  validation rules are retrieved to create client-side validation
  scripts as well as remote validation scripts

For More Info :

```
http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2007/11/20/aspnet-mvc-pipeline-lifecycle/
```

Comment: Do you think it could be Unity cause some problems?

Answer (score 0):

i am sorry for my english

there are many
1.Application_BeginRequest(and AuthenticateRequest) in global or some HttpModule
2.filters
3.mvc framework,controller factory,action invoker and so on
4.when the first time run,it cost many to compile il to native

i think you can use a Stopwatch to check how much time the code in you action spend
so that you can find out where is the point take to much time

120ms is not the time spend before run action ,i think it is time the action done

by the way 120ms is not too bad

**update**

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var profiler = MiniProfiler.Current;
    using (profiler.Step("action"))
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

[image]
this pic is above code run result
so you can see
action is a child only cost 1.9
and http://...... cost 302,it include controller,action

so you should check most time cost inside you action code or outside you action code
in the pic,it cost 300+ because it is 1st run,2nd run is just cost 4
1st run must be slow

Comment: As the profiler shows, this is happening BEFORE my code, so I can't stopwatch it.

Comment: Nope - this isn't the first run, and it's not my action code that is the problem, as you can see from my pic, MY code runs just fine at 20ms, the problem is the HTTP.